# register a custom json with maps

Tags: java, json, mongodb, list

I want to create a json like that :

**Expected result:**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "author": "firas",
    "templatename": "view",
    "typetemp": "factsheet",
    "structure": [
      {
        "nb_columns": 6,
        "title_linechart": "product",
        "xAxis_linechart": "productname",
        "yAxis_linechart": "productcolor"   
      },
      {
       "type": "piechart",
       "percentage" : 81
      },
      {
        ....
      }]
}
```

**The field structure has dynamic fields**

This my Entity:

```
public class Template {

@Id
private String id;  
private String author;
private String templatename;
private String typetemp;
private Map <String, Object> structure;
}
```

Result I had :

```
{
"id": "1",
"author": "firas",
"templatename": "view",
"typetemp": "factsheet",
"structure": {
    "nb_columns": 6,
    "title_linechart": "product",
    "xAxis_linechart": "productname",
    "yAxis_linechart": "productcolor",
    "type": "piechart",
    "percentage" : 81
}
```

So I changed the type of `structure` to `List<Map<String,Object>>` but it gives me this error :

```
Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Which field hold the object `{ "type": "piechart", "percentage" : 81 }`? Your example of json is not a valid json.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @KunLun sorry I edit my post !  I want to get a json like mentionned below in the second line ( I want to transform the field structure to a list of objects)

Comment: After update, `structure` looks like `List<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: Yes I tried to change the type of `structure` to `List<Map<String, Object>>` but it gives me the error `Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class Template {

    private String id;
    private String author;
    private String templatename;
    private String typetemp;
    private List<StructureWrapper> structure;
}

public class StructureWrapper {

    private Map<String, Object> structure;

    @JsonValue
    public Map<String, Object> getStructure() {
        return structure;
    }

    public void setStructure(Map<String, Object> structure) {
    this.structure = structure;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "author": null,
    "templatename": null,
    "typetemp": null,
    "structure": [
        {
            "title_linechart": "product",....
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can't use a class Structure like you mentionned because it has not fixed fields **it has dynamic fields** ! I mean it is not always has the fields nb_columns, title_linechart ... That's why I am using Map<String,Object>

Comment: Check my comment again. I have edited, now should work.

Comment: I got the error :  `Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments `

Comment: I assume that you receive this exception when you call the API that is returning this response? Or what's the use case for it? Could you give us more info about this.